# iPhone - how may I catch a button click in a header view into a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, uibutton, click

I'm planning to build a customized view for the header line of a table view, with a button inside it. I think there will be no problem to do that, but I guess how I'll be able later to know from wich header line the button was clicked ? I guess that didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not be usefull here, and I don't see any didSelectHeaderAtSection method...

Can you tell me a good way to do that stuff ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that once and used the indexPath.row integer, passed that to the (id) sender of the button. That should work just fine.

Edit:

In:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

you create a button.
Then you can do this:

```
button.tag = section;
```

You attach a method to the buttons

```
- (void) myMethod:(id) sender
```

and inside there should be something like this:

```
[(UIButton *)sender tag]
```

That should do the job.

Comment: could you just give me some piece of code that I can understand when (and where) you do the things you do ? Where do you pass the id, how do you define the destination method for the click, etc...

Comment: This works great, even with cells (and some math functions to parse sections and rows :-)  ). Thank you.